# Delay Query Execution During Slicer Filtering

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I currently have about 6 slicers referencing a very large pivot table in Excel. The problem is that every time a slicer filter is selected, it automatically updates the pivot table. I would like to be able to delay the query and select all of my filter values in each slicer, then have the pivot table update once all of these slicer values have been selected.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643025/prevent-excel-from-refreshing-pivot-table-until-told-to-do-so-by-vba . Just need to modify to check for your values and then run the Calculate function.